# Excel: count unique values using SUMPRODUCT with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, count, sum, countif

Ok, I have a sum product working to give me the count of unique values in a column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F2:F38<>"")/COUNTIF(F2:F38,F2:F38))
```

So if I have the numbers: `1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 2` it would return `5`.

But what I want to do is count the number of unique values based upon another number, e.g.:

```
Name:             Sales:
Mike              2
Bob               1
Gary              1
Mike              5
Bob               6
Gary              1
Mike              3
Bob               4
Gary              2
Mike              1
Bob               2
Gary              6
Mike              3
Bob               1
Gary              1
Mike              1
Bob               3
Gary              4
```

It would say that there are `4` unique values for "Name" Mike, 5`unique values for "Name" Bob, and`4`unique values for "Name" Gary. This is because for "Name" Mike there are the numbers`253131`, so the unique numbers are`2531`and therefore the count would return`4`.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: please clarify the desired result, I don't see 4 or 5 in Other Number

Comment: Please clarify. In your first example you're saying "Based on "1", count the unique values. What does that mean?

Comment: @depperm I made a mistake in the question, please see the edit.

Comment: @GisMofx I hope the sentence I have edited in helps, what I mean is I want to see the amount of unique values there are for the "Other Number" 1

Comment: How do you get 3 from the value column where Other number=1? That's the connection I don't think is clear.

Comment: still doesn't make sense, Other Number has 1,2,3 so 3 unique values. 1, 5 for Other Number, 2, 4 for Other Number makes no sense. Please expound. How does Other Number relate to Value

Comment: @GisMofx It should be 4

Comment: Yea, still not clear.

Comment: Thank you. I think I now follow. This is because you are grouping column 1 values and then summarizing/counting unique values for the group. Answer coming shortly....

Comment: Does my solution below address your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.

Insert a cell at the bottom with the value you are trying to count unique for.. So "Gary" at the bottom of your sheet. Create another column to the right of the Sales Column Called "NameValue". Create a formula in this column:

```
=IF(A2=$A$10,B2,"") <-Where $A$10 is the location of "Gary"
```

Then at the bottom of the new column insert this formula:

```
=SUM(IF(C2:C6<>"",1/COUNTIF(C2:C6, C2:C6), 0)) <-Where C2:C6 is your range we just create from above.
```

You might need to press Ctrl+Shift+enter when you type this formula in. Now you can change the value of A12 to any value in the name column and it will spit out the unique count.